# If $2X+3Y\le5$ and $3X+Y\ge10$, how do we formally prove that $2X+3Y+10\le 5+3X+Y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic

Suppose I have two inequalities in $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. For instance,

$$\begin{align}
2X+ 3Y &\le \phantom{1}5 \\
3X+ \phantom{3}Y &\ge 10
\end{align}$$
(The specific inequalities don't matter.) This inequalities are always true for a problem.

If both of them are true, then this inequality must also be true:

$$2X+ 3Y+10 \le 5 +3X+ Y$$

I think is logically correct, but I am not convinced at all. I don't know if this is formal proof. Using inequalities as prepositions and the result of adding them as a deduction ($a\to b$).

Can you give some advice for a formal proof?

Like a book or something like that.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Use $A \le B$ and $\alpha \le \beta\implies A+\alpha \le B + \beta$.  (Let $A= 2x+3y$ and $\alpha = 5$ and $B=10$ and $\beta = 3x+Y$.

Answer (score 5):

You could think of it as $2x+3y=a$ and then you know that $a \leq 5$. Then you have $3x+y$, and let's say that equals $b$ and you know that $10 \leq b$.

If you have $a+10$ we know that $a+10 \leq 5+10$. And we also know that $10 \leq b$ so $a+10 \leq 5+ b$. Substituting back the original formulas for $a$ and $b$, we'd get $2x+3y+10 \leq 5+3x+y$

Answer (score 2):

If $a\le b$ and $c\le d$, then $a+c\le b+d$ (think about why this is true first).

Your example is just an instance of this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$. Then $a + c \leq b + c \leq b + d$. Your result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$2x + 3y \le 5$ and $10 \le 3x + y$ so

If you want to be utterly formal

$2x+ 3y \le 5$ so $2x+3y +10 \le 5 +10$.  And $10\le 3x+y$ so $5+10 \le 5+3x+y$ and by transitivity $2x+3y + 10 \le 5+3x + y$.

But it's enough to just say that if $2x+3y \le 5$ and $10 \le 3x+y$ than $(2x+3) + 10 \le 5+(3x+y)$.